# Node.js: Axios vs Fetch using x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: node.js, axios, http-headers, fetch, x-www-form-urlencoded

I normally use Axios for my API requests, but I'm having an issue hitting an external API with Axios for some reason.

Fetch on the other hand works fine with this particular request.

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Axios:

```js
async function getToken(req, res) {

  const apiCreds = {
        'grant_type' : 'client_credentials',
        'client_id' : xxxxxxxxxxxx,
        'client_secret' : xxxxxxxxxxxx,
        'scope' : 'PublicAPI'
   }

  const header = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
  }
    
  const token = await axios.post(`${process.env.URL}`,qs.stringify(apiCreds),header)
  
  res.status(200).json({'TokenData': token})
}
```

I tried adding `qs.stringify` to the object body, but that didn't work either.

Fetch:

```js
async function getToken(req, res) {
    
    const apiCreds = {
        'grant_type' : 'client_credentials',
        'client_id' : xxxxxxxxxxx,
        'client_secret' : xxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        'scope' : 'PublicAPI'
    }

    fetch(`${process.env.VS_URL}`, {
            method: 'post',
            body:    qs.stringify(apiCreds),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => { res.status(200).json({'TokenData': json}) }); 
            
            
}
```

I really want to know what I'm doing wrong here so I can stick with one package if possible.

Any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This was completely my fault!
I didn't realize the API call actually went through and I was getting a JSON circular error!
I just needed to format the data from the result of the API call.

```
res.status(200).json({'TokenData': token.data.access_token})
```